# How to access package resources as relative

Tags: java, android, resources

This is beginners question. I just started out with Java and Android developing for that matter. Having said that, here is my problem:

I am trying to access a number of bitmaps located in my drawables folder and put them in a file array.

I defined a string:

```
private String pathstring = "/res/drawable";
```

then I am defining a file variable to fill with the information from my string:

```
File folder;
folder = new File(pathstring, "/");
```

to actually get the array I read out the folder variable with listFiles:

```
images = folder.listFiles();
```

Now this doesn't seem to work. I am quite sure that my syntax when defining the pathstring variable is wrong. I have tried `R.drawable` and a lot of other combinations but no avail.

Edit: basically I need a way to access the files in my res/drawables just as I would access resources on my SD-Card and put their names in a file array variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an array of drawables, one way to do it is:

```
private static final int[] imageIds = new int[]{
    R.drawable.image1,
    R.drawable.image2,
    ...};
private static final Drawable[] myImages = new Drawable[imageIds.length];
...
for (int i=0;i<imageIds.length;i++){
    myImages[i] = getResources().getDrawable(imageIds[i])
}
```

This would be the more usual way to access a resource, instead of a `File` array.

Answer (score 0):

The way you access resources in Android is not by hardcoding paths, Instead you should use the `R` class like this `R.drawable.myimage`

Comment: hhafez, thanks for your answer. However I still do not understand how I would go on about filling a file array with the images in my R.drawable class. Any hint?